# For loop generating MemoryError

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, out-of-memory

```
with open(files, "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    totalTweets = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        totalTweets += 1
        hashtagsArr = re.findall(r"#(\w+)", line[2])
        for eachHashtag in hashtagsArr:
            hashtagsArr.append(eachHashtag)
```

Why is the for loop generating memory error for large csv files? I am simply iterating a large csv file.

Comment: You are appending new hashtags to the same list of hashtags you are iterating. That, to me, sounds like a never ending loop: `for eachHashtag in hashtagsArr: hashtagsArr.append(eachHashtag)` may never terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the last loop:

```
for eachHashtag in hashtagsArr:
    hashtagsArr.append(eachHashtag)
```

`hashtagsArr` grows on one element each iteration, so this loop never breaks correctly. When array became too large to be stored in the memory, MemoryError raised.

Otherwise, your code looks fine, enumerate iterated lazily so it doesn't read all file content into the memory at the first call.

If you need to save all hashtags into one list, you can modify your code like following:

```
hashtags=[]
with open(files, "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    totalTweets = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        totalTweets += 1
        hashtagsArr = re.findall(r"#(\w+)", line[2])
        hashtags += hashtagsArr
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for eachHashtag in hashtagsArr: 
    hashtagsArr.append(eachHashtag)
```

This is equivalent to saying for every egg in my basket, add that egg to the basket. This is a loop that will never terminate because you are adding the eggs to the basket at the same rate as you are taking them away. You need to create a new variable to contain hashtag data, you could call it "newHashtagArr" but it doesn't matter.

```
newHashtagArr = []
for eachHashtag in hashtagsArr:
    newHashtagArr.append(eachHashtag)
```

Answer (score 0):

*your correct modified code*

```
newhashtagarr=[]
with open(files, "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    totalTweets = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        totalTweets += 1
        hashtagsArr = re.findall(r"#(\w+)", line[2])
        for eachHashtag in hashtagsArr:
            newhashtagarr.append(eachHashtag)
```